# Woocommerce product description - metadata key?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I would like to re-use the Woocommerce product description in one of my custom widgets.

But I'm having a hard time finding the right description `Metadata Key` for the description content?

Is there one? What is it?

Comment: Or simply `global $post;` and  `echo get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );` for a widget. If you want the short description: `global $post;` and  `echo get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $post->ID );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WooCommerce is retrieved using `the_content()` when on the single product page.  If you are looking to retrieve it in a custom widget you could use something like `echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $product_id))`;